# Unity - NuGet package gets auto-removed

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, nuget

I've created an Unity project, and want to use the OpenNI wrapper from here https://github.com/falahati/NiWrapper.Net.
After adding the NuGet package in JetBrains Rider it appears and is installed correctly (is usable) but after a minute or two -the package disappears and Rider warns me that it can't resolve symbols from the wrapper and the namespace OpenNIWrapper could not be found... But what's strange it still appears in "Packages" of the project.

I'm using the newest MacOS Mojave, already tried on VS for Mac, MonoDevelop and in Rider... I've tried removing the project and creating it from scratch, tried to change API Compatibility Level in Unity - both 4.0 and 2.0 don't work.

I noticed that it does some kind of auto-synchronization or build and deletes the package from .csproj file.

Basically I've run out of ideas and couldn't find any solutions anywhere... I'll appreciate any help, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically following @Radomyr and https://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/unity-and-nuget/ I created a "nuget.config" file telling the project to save packages in the assets - so they are not removed every time:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\Assets\packages" />
      </config>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity do not support nuget. In your case IDE added references for nuget packages to csproj but Unity re-create csproj files after each scripts re-import and remove all other data (which IDE added before).

To use third-party package you can chose any of those ways:

- Just clone/copy repository with third-party plugin to project manually.
- Use git submodules. Like first way but easier to manage. To more info you can see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule
- Build Third-party plugin to DLL and add it to project.
- Use Unity Package Manager. In this case you need manually add dependency to `Packages/manifest.json`. To learn more you can read https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-manifestPrj.html

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it to not remove the package. But now one more error appears... 
`Assembly 'Assets/packages/NiWrapper.Net.x64.2.2.0.35/lib/netstandard2.0/NiWrapper.Net.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'System.Drawing.Common'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?` 

Does that mean that I won't be able to use this package on Mac? :/

Comment: Now I get 3 errors that `Unloading broken assembly Assets/packages/NiWrapper.Net.x86.2.2.0.35/lib/netstandard2.0/NiWrapper.Net.dll, this assembly can cause crashes in the runtime`

Comment: @PiotrAdamczyk try to load needed libs from https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/ . Or check plugin sources - maybe functionality which depends on this libs useless for you and you can just cut those code :)